# New to Unity, Debug.Log not showing on console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an android q&a game for my sisters which is going well for my first time but whenever i try to use this `Debug.Log` it won't show up in the console. I wanted the questions to appear in the console as the game runs to test if it was working or not. Am i doing something wrong here?

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Questions {
   public string question;
   public int answer;
}




using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Questions[] questions; 
    private static List<Questions> unansweredQuestions;

    private Questions currentQuestion;

void start()
{
    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Questions>();   
    }
    GetRandomQuestion();
    Debug.Log(currentQuestion.question + "is" + currentQuestion.answer);
}

void GetRandomQuestion()
{
    int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
    currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];

    unansweredQuestions.RemoveAt(randomQuestionIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: The correct name of the function is `Start`, not `start`. Also, make sure the `info` button (with the white bubble) is checked in the top-right corner of the console tab.

Comment: oh thank you, i thought there was something wrong with the whole thing itself

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Start()` instead of `start()`.